# Safari Web Extension - the service_worker script failed to load due to an error on iOS

Tags: xcode, mobile-safari, manifest, safari-extension, browser-extension

Using mv3, my Safari web extension works fine on macOS but on iOS I get the following error: `the service_worker script failed to load due to an error`

`background.js` has no errors (works with Chrome and on macOS).

Here is how I load the background script in `manifest.json`

```
 "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
```

Anyone encounter this and/or ideas on how to debug this for iOS specifically?

Edit:
Further investigation revealed that it's caused by all of these:

```
browser.runtime.onStartup.addListener(async () => {
  ....
});
```

browser.runtime.onStartup.addListener(async () => {
....
});

```
browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
... 
});
```

Even just providing a nothing but a console log in any of those three runtime options causes the extension to crash/show the service_worker error.

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
...
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Abandoned Safari extension all together - just a huge headache.

Comment: Earlier this week I did a deep dive scraping the internet for answers because I had the same issue. I found that I had added the background script after the chrome to Safari conversion. As such it was not included in the Build Phases. Adding it to the build phases fixed my issue.